# Creating hash of hash dynamically in perl

Tags: perl, hash, hash-of-hashes

I am trying to create a hash of hash of - the nesting depth depends on the number of arguments passed into `@aGroupByFields` array.

In the below implementation, I am getting the desired hash structure.But I have hard coded the fields [ example - `$phBugRecord->{createdBy}` ] instead of deriving it from the array.

I am not sure how to dynamically create this.

```
my (@aGroupByFields) = ['createdBy','status','devPriority']; 
# In real case,these are passed in as arguments

my (%hTemp); 
# This is the final hash which will be structured according to above fields

# %hBugDetails is the hash containing details of all bugs

foreach my $phBugRecord ( @{ $hBugDetails{records} } ) {

    # The below statement needs to be generated dynamically as 
    # opposed to the hard-coded values.
    push(
        @{
            $hTemp{ $phBugRecord->{createdBy} }{ $phBugRecord->{status} }
                { $phBugRecord->{devPriority} }
        },
        $phBugRecord
    );

}
```

Any pointer will be a great help.Thanks.

Comment: You don't want to generate the statement. You want to generate the hash. But why do you want that?

Comment: Please refer below question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558981/dynamically-recursively-building-hashes-in-perl I hope that helps!

Comment: See [`Data::Diver`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Diver) and [`Deep::Hash::Utils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Deep::Hash::Utils)

Comment: @simbabque : The hash, thus generated , will be consumed to render a bug report.The bug report will be then able to show the bugs grouped by createdBy > status > devPriority. [ In short, I am given a list of groupBy fields and a dump of all bug records -  and I need to return a hash which should group the bug records appropriately].Thanks for the edit anyways.Cheers.

Comment: So you want to auto-group.

Comment: @simbabque : Yes - exactly.The number of groupBy fields are not constant - so I guess this "auto-group" is the best approach.But if there are better ways, I am more than willing to change my approach here.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I didn't know Data::Diver. That's fun, especially that it can be an lvalue. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do what you need

```
my @aGroupByFields = qw/ createdBy status devPriority /;

my %hTemp;

for my $phBugRecord ( @{ $hBugDetails{records} } ) {

    my $hash = \%hTemp;

    for my $field ( @aGroupByFields ) {

        my $key = $phBugRecord->{$field};

        if ( $field eq $aGroupByFields[-1] ) {
            push @{ $hash->{ $key } }, $phBugRecord;
        }
        else {
            $hash = $hash->{ $key } //= {};
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm.Gave me back exactly what I wanted.I know I am asking for too much here - can you please explain the code $hash = $hash->{ $key } //= {}; Thanks a lot for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working implementation with [Data::Diver](http://p3rl.org/Data::Diver).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Diver 'DiveVal';
use Data::Printer;

my %hBugDetails = (
    records => [
        {
            createdBy   => 'created_by1',
            status      => 'status1',
            devPriority => 'dev_priority1',
            foo         => 'foo1',
            bar         => 'bar1',
        },
        {
            createdBy   => 'created_by1',
            status      => 'status2',
            devPriority => 'dev_priority2',
            foo         => 'foo',
            bar         => 'bar',
        },
    ],
);

# we want to group by these fields
my @group_by = ( 'createdBy', 'status', 'devPriority' );

my $grouped_bugs = {};    # for some reason we need to start with an empty hashref
foreach my $bug ( @{ $hBugDetails{records} } ) {

    # this will auto-vivify the hash for us
    push @{ DiveVal( $grouped_bugs, map { $bug->{$_} } @group_by ) }, $bug;
}

p $grouped_bugs;
```

The output looks like this.

```
\ {
    created_by1   {
        status1   {
            dev_priority1   [
                [0] {
                    bar           "bar1",
                    createdBy     "created_by1",
                    devPriority   "dev_priority1",
                    foo           "foo1",
                    status        "status1"
                }
            ]
        },
        status2   {
            dev_priority2   [
                [0] {
                    bar           "bar",
                    createdBy     "created_by1",
                    devPriority   "dev_priority2",
                    foo           "foo",
                    status        "status2"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I renamed your variables. It was very hard to read the code like that. It makes more sense to just use speaking names instead of cryptic abbreviations for the *type* of variable. The sigil already does that for you.